# Combine the output of different queries as a single query output

Tags: mysql, sql, monetdb

How do I combine the output of different queries.

I have the following sql queries with the output:

```
1) select d.departmentid, d.name, count(distinct(sg.personid)) as noOfStudents from department d inner join course c on c.departmentid = d.departmentid inner join student_grade sg on sg.courseid = c.courseid group by d.departmentid, d.name;
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| departmentid | name         | noofstudents |
+==============+==============+==============+
|          101 | Computer Sci |            1 |
|          104 | Mech         |            2 |
|          103 | EEE          |            1 |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+



2) select d.departmentid, d.name, count(distinct(ci.personid)) as noOfTeachers from department d inner join course c on c.departmentid = d.departmentid inner join course_instructor ci on ci.courseid = c.courseid group by d.departmentid, d.name;
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| departmentid | name         | noofteachers |
+==============+==============+==============+
|          101 | Computer Sci |            1 |
|          103 | EEE          |            2 |
|          104 | Mech         |            1 |
|          102 | ECE          |            3 |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+

3) select d.departmentid, d.name, count(distinct(c.courseid)) as noOfCourses from department d inner join course c on c.departmentid = d.departmentid group by d.departmentid, d.name;
+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| departmentid | name         | noofcourses |
+==============+==============+=============+
|          101 | Computer Sci |           3 |
|          102 | ECE          |           3 |
|          104 | Mech         |           1 |
|          103 | EEE          |           2 |
+--------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Now I want to combine all three into a single table to display the data.
How can I do that?

Here I am trying UNION operation and is it good to use?

Comment: what is your expected result from 3 as all the 3 count is different

Comment: It creates a table of 3 columns with 11 tuples, but it should create table with 5 columns with 4 tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get *Students*, *Teachers* and *Courses* as separate columns in the output, you can try something like this:

```
select 
    d.departmentid, d.name, 
    count(distinct(sg.personid)) as noOfStudents, 
    0 as noofteachers, 0 as noofcourses 
from 
    department d 
inner join 
    course c on c.departmentid = d.departmentid 
inner join 
    student_grade sg on sg.courseid = c.courseid 
group by 
    d.departmentid, d.name

UNION ALL

select 
    d.departmentid, d.name, 0 as noOfStudents,
    count(distinct(ci.personid)) as noOfTeachers, 0 as noofcourses 
from 
    department d 
inner join 
    course c on c.departmentid = d.departmentid 
inner join 
    course_instructor ci on ci.courseid = c.courseid 
group by 
    d.departmentid, d.name

UNION ALL

select 
    d.departmentid, d.name, 0 as noOfStudents, 
    0 as noofteachers, count(distinct(c.courseid)) as noOfCourses 
from 
    department d 
inner join 
    course c on c.departmentid = d.departmentid 
group by 
    d.departmentid, d.name
```

This should produce something like this:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+  
| departmentid | name         | noofstudents | noofteachers | noofcourses  |  
+==============+==============+==============+==============+==============+  
|          101 | Computer Sci |             1|             0|             0|  
|          104 | Mech         |             2|             0|             0|  
|          103 | EEE          |             1|             0|             0|  
|          101 | Computer Sci |             0|             1|             0|  
|          103 | EEE          |             0|             2|             0|  
|          104 | Mech         |             0|             1|             0|  
|          102 | ECE          |             0|             3|             0|  
|          101 | Computer Sci |             0|             0|             3|  
|          102 | ECE          |             0|             0|             3|  
|          104 | Mech         |             0|             0|             1|  
|          103 | EEE          |             0|             0|             2|  
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

If you need aggregated values, just enclose the entire query into brackets and sum the results

```
SELECT 
    departmentid, name, 
    SUM(noOfStudents), SUM(noOfTeachers), SUM(noOfCourses)
FROM 
    (Query1 UNION ALL Query2 UNION ALL Query3) AS mySubQuery
GROUP BY 
    departmentid, name
```

Comment: Its giving error as subquery table reference needs alias, use AS xxx in: "select departmentid, name, sum(noofcourses),sum(noofteachers),sum(noofstudents) "
syntax error, unexpected BY in: "by"

Answer (score 0):

You could use a inner join for get all result on same row

```
  select  t0.departmentid
        , t0.name
        , t1.noOfStudents
        , t2.noOfTeachers 
        , t3.noOfCourses 
  from department t0
  left join 
  (
  select d.departmentid
    , d.name
    , count(distinct(sg.personid)) as noOfStudents
  from department d 
  inner join course c on c.departmentid = d.departmentid 
  inner join student_grade sg on sg.courseid = c.courseid 
  group by d.departmentid, d.name
  ) t1 ON t0.departmentid = t1.departmentid
  left join (
    select d.departmentid
      , d.name
      , count(distinct(ci.personid)) as noOfTeachers 
    from department d 
    inner join course c on c.departmentid = d.departmentid 
    inner join course_instructor ci on ci.courseid = c.courseid 
    group by d.departmentid, d.name
  ) t2 on t0.departmentid = t2.departmentid 
  left join  (
    select d.departmentid
    , d.name
    , count(distinct(c.courseid)) as noOfCourses 
    from department d 
    inner join course c on c.departmentid = d.departmentid 
    group by d.departmentid, d.name
  ) t3 on t0.departmentid = t3.departmentid
```

or if you need  the resul on  separated rows you could use UNION ALL